# Jquery each and Selector behaving differently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I created a function in Jquery which is supposed to center elements vertically (I could not do it using css, got tired and just made it programically ^^). The problem now is that I initially created it using .each, and then, since it was already creator, I tried calling it using the selector ($('something').center), but it is behaving differently for some reason.

Using the selector, it seems to be doing just the same to every element. It does it with the first element, and then just applies all values to the remaining elements. So, for example, my function takes the element height and does some operations with it, but the selector just takes the first one and then applies its parameters to everyone..

I'll keep using each since it works best right now, but I still can't understand why they are doing that..

Centering Function:

```
$.fn.center = function (){
/*If this is the highest element, or
  if this element has full use of the width,
  then there's no need to align it.
 */

if(this.height() == this.parent().height() ||
this.width() == this.parent().width())
{
    this.css({
        position : "relative",
        top : 0
    });
}
else //Should be aligned.
{
    this.css({
        position : "relative",
        top : (this.parent().height()/2)-(this.height()/2)
    });
}
return this; //Used for chaining.
```

};

Here's an example of what I mean ^^
http://jsfiddle.net/lrojas94/pmbttrt2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple things, like just changing the CSS in the same way for all elements with the same class, you can call it directly without using `.each()`. For example:

```
$('.elem').css('color', '#fff');
```

But if each of the divs needs to end up with an individual value, you should use `.each()`. For example (sorry it's a bit weird):

```
var border = 1;
$('.elem').each(function() {
    $(this).css('border', border + 'px solid #000');
    border += 1;
});
```

Basically, if you don't use `.each()`, it'll check what you want to change (just once!) and apply it to all elements with that class. If you do use `.each()`, it'll do it individually for each element.

Comment: Not too sure how that answers the question?

Comment: The question was why that "Jquery each and Selector" behave differently; that is what I tried to answer...

Comment: Yeah it does :) Thanks a lot in fact!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, `this` within a jQuery plugin function is not a DOM node. It's the jQuery object that wraps around all the nodes that were matched by the selector.

Your function's body should rather look like:

```
return this.each(function () {
    var $el = $(this);

    //centering logic for $el goes here
});
```

Comment: @Godisgood Doesn't want to load somehow, but basically replace all the code you have inside your plugin's function by the code I wrote in the answer. Then, take all your previous code and put it after `var $el = ...;` and finally replace `this` for `$el` everywhere in your old code.

Comment: I used "this" because I tried to follow the Jquery plug-ins tutorial. Here's a link: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/                   It states that you should use this instead of $this